How to inspect pop-up window when right click is not working? (Selenium VBA)
I need to click OK on a pop-up window, but right click is not working when the pop-up window is open (I can't inspect the element). If I leave Inspect window open, there is nothing happening. Please see the screenshots.
Popup screenshot
Webpage code
I haven't tried much as I don't know what element it is. I guess this website is using Java, I'm not familiar with it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

That dialog is not HTML, it's a JavaScript alert. You need to switch to the Alert and then Accept it.
Code sample
Sub Test()
    Dim popup As Selenium.Alert
    Set driver = New Selenium.ChromeDriver
    With driver
        .Get "http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/javascript_alerts"
        .FindElementByCss("button[onclick='jsConfirm()']").Click
        Set popup = .SwitchToAlert(Raise:=False)
        popup.Accept
    End With
End Sub


Thank you JeffC! I'm not a programmer, so need more details, but I get the idea. Question: the link you use in the code - is it going to be the link to my website plus javascript_alerts as well? Find element by css - is it the same text as in your code or where do I look for it?
